# Node version showing 10.0 but while creating a new angular project showing current version 4.2.6. How do i remove 4.2.6?

Tags: node.js

I am trying to install the angular latest version to my ubuntu 16.0.4 but while installing packages I am getting an error stating that my version is 4.2.6 and when I try node -v its showing 10.0 as version. How do i remove node completely i tried installing using PPA it shows the version selected but it does not work while installing angular. Can someone give me a better way to install node and npm?

https://askubuntu.com/questions/786015/how-to-remove-nodejs-from-ubuntu-16-04
tried this but still, the version is showing as 10.0

Comment: are you using the angular cli to start a new project?

Comment: Yes i am using ng new to create a new project

Comment: also, it looks like you're asking 2 seperate questions. for a better way to install node and npm you can use nvm (node version manager). for angular you can try updating the cli

Comment: Can you show the actual error message?

Comment: using NVM fixed the issue. But now its showing that `bash: /usr/bin/ng: No such file or directory`